# Поиск утечки памяти в скрипте на php5.6

Tags: php, mysqli, php5

> К сожалению не могу предоставить исходный код скрипта и тут только примеры когда в которых по моему мнению может быть утечка.

Скрипт на php работает в фоне, обрабатывает все в несколько процессов работа с процессами - есть основной процесс и он только плодит детей с целью обработки, дочерние процессы скачивает zip архивы с ftp, вытаскивает из zip все xml файлы после чего обрабатывает их и записывает в mysql.

И интересен способ нахождения утечи, скрипт работает долго несколько дней от 1 до 3. Спустя какое-то время использует всю память на сервере и сервер перестает отвечать.

Возможные причины утечки (упрощенная версия, отсутствуют проверки что файл был скачен, обработки xml и отправка его в базу и поиск новых zip файлов):

```
// Скачиваем архив и отправляем путь до файла в функцию, около 430000 zip файлов 
function start(){
    $file_loc = fopen(local_dir.ftp_zip, 'w');

    if(@ftp_fget($conn_id, $file_loc, $ftp_zip, FTP_BINARY)) {
        $this->open_zip(local_dir.$ftp_zip, $link_sql);
    }
    unlink(local_dir.ftp_zip);
}

 // Вытаскиваем из zip xml файлы
function open_zip($file, $link_sql){
     $zip = new ZipArchive;
        if($zip->open($file) == TRUE) {
            // Обычно в 1 архиве от 10000 до 100000 xml файлов  
            for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i ++) {
                $filename_full = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
                $filename = explode('_', $filename_full)[0];

                // Отправляем $xml_text в приватную функцию 
                xml_to_sql($zip->getFromName($filename_full), $link_sql)

            }
        }
    }
}

// Преобразуем xml в SimpleXMLElement, где $xml_text это строка в формате xml
function xml_to_sql($xml_text, $link_sql){
    foreach(new SimpleXMLElement($xml_text) as $xml) {
       break;
    }
}
```

Код пораждения дочерних процессов:

```
class daemon_regions {
    // Список обрабатываемых регионов
    private $regions = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3'];
    // Максимальное количество дочерних процессов
    public $maxProcesses = 10;
    // Когда установится в TRUE, демон завершит работу
    protected $stop_server = FALSE;
    // Здесь будем хранить запущенные дочерние процессы
    protected $currentJobs = array();

    public function __construct() {
        // Ждем сигналы SIGTERM и SIGCHLD
        pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, array($this, "childSignalHandler"));
        pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, array($this, "childSignalHandler"));
    }

    // Родитель плодит детей
    public function run() {
        // Пока $stop_server не установится в TRUE, гоняем бесконечный цикл
        foreach($this->regions as $name) {
            // Если уже запущено максимальное количество дочерних процессов, ждем их завершения
            $flud_off = True;
            while(count($this->currentJobs) >= $this->maxProcesses) {
                if($flud_off) { $flud_off = False; }
                sleep(10);
            }
            if(!$this->stop_server) {
                $this->launchJob($name, $settings);
            }
        }
        while($this->currentJobs != []) { sleep(1); }
    }

    // Создает дочерний процесс
    protected function launchJob($name) {

        // Создаем дочерний процесс
        // весь код после pcntl_fork() будет выполняться
        // двумя процессами: родительским и дочерним
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if($pid == - 1) {
            // Не удалось создать дочерний процесс
            return FALSE;
        } elseif($pid) {
            // Этот код выполнится родительским процессом
            $this->currentJobs[$pid] = TRUE;
        } else {
            // А этот код выполнится дочерним процессом
            $start = time();

            $dm = new daemon_region_parser();
            $dm->main($name);

            $today_summ = gmdate("H:i:s", time() - $start);

            exit();
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

    // Обработка получаемых UNIX сигналов
    public function childSignalHandler($signo, $pid = null, $status = null) {
        switch ($signo) {
            case SIGTERM:
                // При получении сигнала завершения работы устанавливаем флаг
                $this->stop_server = true;
                break;
            case SIGCHLD:
                // При получении сигнала от дочернего процесса
                if(!$pid) {
                    $pid = pcntl_waitpid(- 1, $status, WNOHANG);
                }
                // Пока есть завершенные дочерние процессы
                while($pid > 0) {
                    if($pid && isset($this->currentJobs[$pid])) {
                        // Удаляем дочерние процессы из списка
                        unset($this->currentJobs[$pid]);
                    }
                    $pid = pcntl_waitpid(- 1, $status, WNOHANG);
                }
                break;
            default:
                // все остальные сигналы
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Использую php v5.6, mysql и модуль mysqli.

О сервере: тестировал на VPS SMP Debian v3.16.36, 2 ядра и 58ГБ ОЗУ, и еще на сервере под управлением SMP Debian 3.16.36, 12 ядрами с и 64 ГБ ОЗУ.

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что тут сам собой напрашивается анекдот "- Мне Карузо совсем не нравится, поет ужасно! - А где ты его слышал? - Да мне Рабинович напел.". Для начала попробуйте помониторьте сервер тупым `top`, посмотрите какие именно процессы жрут память.

Comment: @rjhdby как раз речь и идет об скрипте на php, мониторил через htop, жрет дочерние процессы, и код из дочернего процесса в котором может быть проблема я привел в пример.

Comment: Каким образом запускаются дочерние процессы? Один раз в начале и висят в памяти или при каждой итерации запускаются, отрабатывают и гаснут? Те процессы, которые жрут - время запуска какое, только что или 1-3 дня назад?

Comment: @rjhdby обновил ответ, но не зависимо от количества дочерних процессов, дочерний процесс умудряется съедать всю память.

Comment: И все же повторю вопрос, дабы исключить очевидные вещи Те процессы, которые жрут - время запуска какое, только что или 1-3 дня назад?

Comment: @rjhdby да, немного не правильно написал, весь скрипт отрабатывает за 1-3 дня, дочерние процессы живет максимум час и они съедают всю память. Все процессы порождает 1 родитель и вот он работает как раз 1-3 дня.

Comment: Даже скорее так https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62468

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала вариант определения, куда уходит память: воспользуйтесь каким-нибудь профилировщиком, умеющим мониторить память. Скорей всего включенный профилировщик резко просадит производительность скрипта, да и отчёт использования за 2 дня может быть слишком огромен, так что лучше ограничьте объём работы для запуска с профилировщиком каким-нибудь более компактным значением. [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880458/php-memory-profiling) советует профилировщики:

- [Xhprof](https://github.com/phacility/xhprof) + [Xhgui](https://github.com/perftools/xhgui)
- [php-memprof](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler)
- [Google gperftools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools)

`xdebug`, к сожалению, память не отслеживает.

Казалось, можно бы по старинке натыкать вызовы `memory_get_usage` или `memory_get_peak_usage`, но это мало того, что неудобно - эти функции не могут отслеживать память, выделенную для библиотек. Например, выделенную внутри `libxml2`, которую использует `simplexml`.

И вот на `simplexml` у меня и основное подозрение, что он не возвращает всю занятую память.

---

Имеет смысл распилить задачу на конвеер. `PHP` архитектурно слабо заточен для долгоживущих скриптов.

- Одна группа скриптов ходит по сети и загружает файлики. Сетевой ввод-вывод обычно штука медленная, в варианте перезаписи потока в файловый дескриптор расход памяти будет довольно мал даже для очень длительных скриптов. Информацию о скачанном файлике публиковать в очередь задач. Если поизвращаться с `multicurl`'ом, то это может быть и один скрипт, качающий в много потоков.
- вторая группа подписана на очередь новых архивов, распаковывает архив на отдельные xml и кладёт задачи по их обработке в другую очередь. Можно перезапускать воркер, например, после каждых 10 распакованных файлов, если окажется, что течёт ziparchive. Или вообще дёргать системный unzip вместо ziparchive.
- третья группа читает очередь xml готовых к обработке и уже читает-пишет mysql. Тоже можно легко и безболезненно перезапускать.

Такая архитектура на первый взгляд более сложна, но позволяет проще отслеживать, на каком этапе затыки, добавлять новых воркеров именно на обработку этого этапа или целиком заменять обработчиков именно этого участка. Обработчик может легко помереть и перезапуститься без необходимости, например, выкачивать крупный архив заново и целиком его обходить, хотя умерли обработав уже 999 из 1000 файлов.

Comment: Кроме того стоит заметить, что подобный подход, при его "кажущейся" сложности, будет гораздо более удобен для восприятия, чем игры с `fork` в пределах одного куска кода

Comment: Думаю пора уже переходить на конвеерный вариант, но на данный момент похоже на утечку в SimpleXML.

Answer (score 1):

Как часто у вас обрабатываются файлы? Как часто отрабатывает GC?

Можно попробовать так

```
function xml_to_sql($xml_text, $link_sql){
    $xmlTree = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_text);

    foreach($xmlTree as $xml) {
       break;
    }

    unset($xmlTree);
}
```

Также попробуйте добавить, после цикла

```
$zip->close();
gc_collect_cycles();
```

Comment: Промежуток между zip от 0.3 секунд до 1 минуты, на данный момент GC отрабатывает только при завершении дочернего процесса, возможно в этом и проблема.