# PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated ) (tried to allocate bytes) на VPS

Tags: php

Всем добрый вечер, довольно глупый вопрос, но уже начинаю сходить с ума (знаю, что тема, возможно, дубликат, но решения так и не нашел). 
Есть VPS. Debian 9 x32, Maria DB, Nginx, php-fpm7.0

```
Память RAM: 2048 Мб 
Память SSD: 40000 Мб
CPU:    2x2.8 Ghz
```

Серв абсолютно чистый, сегодня утром купил, нагрузки никакой. Залил на него новый сайт (Opencart 2.1 с шаблоном и набором модулей). Сайт только с разработки, т.е никаких "костылей" и "велосипедов" на нем нет. Модули все покупные и минимальный набор. И при запуске сего чуда вылезает ошибка

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1826619392) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/tytmodno/tm-shop/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7
```

Ошибка не новая и всем известно что лечится она увеличением memory_limit. Увеличил параметр до 512М я получил такой ответ

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/tytmodno/tm-shop/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7
```

Ну и для верности эффекта я задал memory_limit = -1 и получил то же самое

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1824522240) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/tytmodno/tm-shop/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php `memory_limit`

Comment: проверьте сколько съедает на сервере разработки?

Answer (score 2):

1824522240 байт = 1781760 кб = 1740 мб
Нет у вас столько памяти на вашей VPS.

Идите в код [с профилировщиком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598111/203622) и ищите, на какие такие надобности скрипт хочет 2гб памяти сожрать при обработке одного (!) запроса.

Comment: по-моему наоборот, написано, что именно столько и есть, и вся израсходована.

Comment: Скрипту уже выделено 1740мб, скрипт хочет ещё, а ос отвечает "больше памяти нет".

Comment: дак вот именно что, а вы просто заявляете, что столько памяти нет. не больше нет, а столько нет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Буду искать с чего вдруг опенкарту понадобилось столько памяти

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, может поможет кому с подобной проблемой. Решил установкой в конфиге подключением через pdo а не mysqli. После этого сайту хватило memory_limit = 256M

Answer (score 0):

sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024

sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1

sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]