# Как исправить ошибку PHP Fatal error: Out of memory?

Tags: php, fastcgi

Здравствуйте.
У меня не работает сервер - *ошибка 502* в течение 25 минут, в логах вижу следующие:

> 2017/08/19 19:36:30 [error] 7652#0: *978 upstream sent unexpected
>   FastCGI record: 3 while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   207.46.13.158, server: vamdodoma.ru, request: "GET /catalog/2-mestnye-divany/S39861885.html/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/php-nginx/14617404421463.sock/socket:", host:
>   "vamdodoma.ru"
>
> 2017/08/19 19:36:31 [error] 7651#0: *622 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP
>   Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 262144) (tried to allocate
>   8589938688 bytes) in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header
>   from upstream, client: 46.237.19.175, server: vamdodoma.ru, request:
>   "GET /api/app.getCities HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/php-nginx/14617404421463.sock/socket:", host:
>   "vamdodoma.ru"
>
> 2017/08/19 19:36:31 [error] 7651#0: *622 upstream sent unexpected
>   FastCGI record: 3 while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   46.237.19.175, server: vamdodoma.ru, request: "GET /api/app.getCities HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/php-nginx/14617404421463.sock/socket:", host:
>   "vamdodoma.ru"

сервер PHP, NGINX, MySQL

`в php.ini memory_limit = 48000M`

Почему не хватает памяти? Как можно победить эту проблему, чтобы сайт не лежал по 25 минут?
Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А у вас памяти на сервере действительно есть на 48 Гигабайт?

Comment: нет)) у меня 30ГБ, но все же, ему доступно почему-то только 8589938688 bytes

Comment: 30ГБ это неплохо) А свободные 8ГБ точно есть? Или, может, скрипт запускается несколько раз, каждый из них кушает по 8ГБ, и в итоге все ваши 30ГБ кончаются? :)

Comment: Вообще я бы вам крайне рекомендовал проверить и оптимизировать код ваших скриптов (если я правильно предполагаю, что дело именно в них), чтобы ему не нужно было жрать целых 8ГБ, это как-то очень дофига

Comment: да я понимаю, но я не понимаю, какой скрипт это делает..... какой запрос начинает жрать помять...
команда top есть на сервере, но в ней тоже только процессы, а вот кто их запустил и откуда - не ясно

Answer (score 1):

Так в логе же написан и домен и request. Найдите кто обработчик этого request и копайте его.

> PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 262144) (tried to allocate 8589938688 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Что в ошибке ещё сказано примечательного:

- выделил скрипт себе только 256кб, ещё 8гб он только пытается выделить
- при том, что интересно, пытается взять 8гб памяти одним куском
- пытается взять где-то неявно, раз сообщение об ошибке не показывает конкретный скрипт. Например, в подключаемой PECL-библиотеке или скомпилированной встроенной
- памяти свободной нет именно физически. Если запрос упирается в `memory_limit` - то сообщение другое, `Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted`

Вы что-то странное делаете в коде. Берите проблемный запрос, [профилировщик по вкусу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598111/203622) и исследуете код, куда вы деваете память. Ну или ставить ещё памяти, в современный сервер можно и несколько ТБ поставить, есть ещё куда расти ;-)

Comment: Добавление памяти серверу не факт что поможет. Ведь скрипт хочет одним куском, а фрагментация будет постепенно накапливаться.

Comment: хм, кстати да, о фрагментации не подумал.