# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 4731174912 bytes exhausted. Где увеличить?

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс, debian

Непонятно почему в один прекрасный день скрипт стал выбрасывать ошибку

> **PHP Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 4731174912 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 256 bytes) in
>   /var/www/html/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/usertype.php on line
>   2807

причем размер 4731174912 во всех случаях один и тот же и в разных файлах (ошибка).
Пытались увеличить лимит в `my.cnf`, но результата это не дало.
На сервере 16 Гб, но почему-то упирается именно в 4731174912.

Где можно увеличить лимит памяти, или может причина в чем-то другом?

usertype.php:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

database.php:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где сам скрипт

Comment: Почему вы пытаетесь увеличивать лимит в my.cnf, если ошибка возникает в PHP?

Comment: 4,5гб на один запрос? Мда... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598111/203622 для исправления, memory_limit в php.ini для зарывания головы в песок.

Comment: Покажите 2807 строку файла usertype.php и  десяток строк до и после этой строки

Comment: Да, пока зароем голову, потом разбираться будем. Скрипт просто жизненно важен - считает зарплату)

Comment: Поменял memory_limit с 128М на 256М, все-равно ошибка:"PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4731174912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8208 bytes) in /var/www/html/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/database.php on line 1365"

Comment: Или мало? Сколько поставить?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov добавил скрин.

Answer (score 2):

1. выполните вместо вашего кода phpinfo(), посмотрите текущий memory_limit, посмотрите где лежит ваш php.ini
2. отредактируйте его, измените memory_limit на значение побольше
3. перезапустите веб-сервер, если php - модуль apache (или fpm)
4. проверьте в phpinfo, что изменения применены
5. если изменения не применены - то или вы отредактировали не тот конфиг, или не правильно осуществили перезапуск, или управляется где-то в вашем коде (значение можно выставить в скрипте при помощи инструкции ini_set("memory_limit", "<объем_памяти>")

но все это не решение проблемы. 4+Гб на 1 хит - это сверхмного, такого быть не должно, код нужно оптимизировать.

Comment: Всё именно так, phpinfo показывает 256М. Да, это ненормальная ситуация, надо разбираться. Странно, внезапно с 1-го числа это началось... И по коммитам смотрю - предыдущий 26.04, следующий 5.05. Т.е., ничего не менялось...

Comment: то что код стал "кушать" память еще не говорит о том что это произошло из-за изменений в нем. вполне возможно что на старых входных данных код работал обратно, но тем не менее содержал ошибку, которая проявилась при изменении данных

Comment: Хочется увидеть решение проблемы в виде увеличения памяти, хотя бы. Сколько нужно поставить? 10Гб?

Comment: Алгоритм выше, ищите конфиги, правьте, перезапускайте сервер. Ну и надо проверить что лимит не устанавливается где-то в коде приложения через ini_set

Comment: Так я нашел конфиг, в php.ini значение memory_limit увеличил с 128M до 256М. Результат не изменился. Вопрос - я все правильно делаю? Стоит увеличивать и далее?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если скрипт упирается в 4731174912 байт, то если я значение memory_limit увеличу, допустим, до 10000М, то он отработает? Вот тут пробел у меня.

Comment: Увеличил до 8192М, результат тот же: "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4731174912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8208 bytes) in /var/www/html/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/database.php on line 1365"

Comment: Не там увеличиваю?

Comment: а вы после увеличения проверили phphinfo? какое там значение у memory_limit?